# Получить значение value текущего элемента

Tags: jquery

Есть список товаров

```
  <div class="button-group">
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group-gv">
    <div class="number" id="number">
        <button class="minus">-</button>
        <input type="text" value="1" size="2" id="input-quantity" class="input-quantity {{ product.product_id }}"/>
        <button class="plus">+</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="bttn1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_wishlist }}" onclick="wishlist.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="bttn2" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ button_cart }}</span></button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

{{ product.product_id }} уникален для каждого товара
Как при нажатии на кнопку добавления товара .bttn2 получить значение value элемента input только для этого элемента?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var cart = {};
  cart.add = function (id){
    var input = $("#js-quantity-"+id);
    if (input.length) {
      console.log(input.val());
    }
  }
</script>

 <div class="button-group">
  <div class="form-group" id="form-group-gv">
    <div class="number" id="number">
        <button class="minus">-</button>
        <input type="text" value="1" size="2" id="js-quantity-{{ product.product_id }}" class="input-quantity {{ product.product_id }}"/>
        <button class="plus">+</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="bttn1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_wishlist }}" onclick="wishlist.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="bttn2" onclick="cart.add({{ product.product_id }});"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ button_cart }}</span></button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: сработала такая конструкция   var singleValue = $("#js-quantity-" + product_id).val();
  console.log(singleValue);

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" class="bttn2" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.product_id }}');">

cart.add = function(productId){
  var v = $(".input-quantity." + productId).val();
  console.log(v);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

сработала такая конструкция

```
var singleValue = $("#js-quantity-" + product_id).val();
console.log(singleValue);
```

Комментарии помогли)))Спасибо